# iOS Constraints Not Updating After Setting Programatically

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, autolayout

I'm trying to position all the ui objects when loading, but it doesn't seem to change. From top to bottom, the layout is : host, port, user, and password, and I aligned:
* middle of all with middle of view
* top of host with top of layout margin
* top of port with bottom of host
* top of user with bottom of port
* top of password with bottom of user
Could someone please help? Here's the code. Thank you!

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    host.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo:self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    host.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo:self.view.layoutMarginsGuide.topAnchor, constant:20.0).isActive = true
    port.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo:self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    port.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo:host.bottomAnchor, constant:20.0).isActive = true
    user.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo:self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    user.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo:port.bottomAnchor, constant:20.0).isActive = true
    password.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo:self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    password.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo:user.bottomAnchor, constant:20.0).isActive = true
    connectButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo:self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    connectButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo:password.bottomAnchor, constant:20.0).isActive = true
    self.view.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
    self.view.setNeedsLayout()
    self.view.updateConstraints()
}
```

Then I get many of these errors in the console:

```
[LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want.
Try this:
(1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect;
(2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it.
(Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints)
(
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x174288930 h=--& v=--& UITextField:0x10141f240.midY == 256   (active)>",
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x174288980 h=--& v=--& UITextField:0x10141f240.height == 30   (active)>",
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x17028dac0 h=--& v=--& UIButton:0x10131e3a0'Connect'.midY == 325.5   (active)>",
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x17028db10 h=--& v=--& UIButton:0x10131e3a0'Connect'.height == 45   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x174287df0 V:[UITextField:0x10141f240]-(20)-[UIButton:0x10131e3a0'Connect']   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x174287df0 V:[UITextField:0x10141f240]-(20)-[UIButton:0x10131e3a0'Connect']   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

Comment: its not easy to find the issue with the provided data  better you debug it yourself using symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints

Comment: Take ref : http://www.knowstack.com/swift-nslayoutconstraint-programatically-sample-code/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you don't turn off `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` on your widgets `host`, `port`, `user`, `password` and `connectButton` so for these, `NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint`s will be generated which collide with your constraints.

You could for example insert this

```
for view in [host, port, user, password, connectButton] as [UIView] {
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
}
```

into your `viewDidLoad` method, right after `self.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`.

You can also remove your attempts to consider your constraints at the end so your code will look like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    for view in [host, port, user, password, connectButton] as [UIView] {
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    }
    host.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo:self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    host.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo:self.view.layoutMarginsGuide.topAnchor, constant:20.0).isActive = true
    port.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo:self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    port.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo:host.bottomAnchor, constant:20.0).isActive = true
    user.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo:self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    user.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo:port.bottomAnchor, constant:20.0).isActive = true
    password.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo:self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    password.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo:user.bottomAnchor, constant:20.0).isActive = true
    connectButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo:self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    connectButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo:password.bottomAnchor, constant:20.0).isActive = true
}
```

You will then realize that you might want to add a few width constraints on your (what I suppose are) text fields ;).

Anyways, if you prefer to deactivate `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` in Interface Builder, please see [this answer on "Unexpected NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint adding UIView from nib to autolayout storyboard scene"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25101957/unexpected-nsautoresizingmasklayoutconstraint-adding-uiview-from-nib-to-autolayo/25105789#25105789).